# Rails Multi Tenancy seeding issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, multi-tenant, seeding

I created a multi tenancy app with Apartment gem and rails 5. I successfully create a new tenant, but I want to seed it. When I run the seeds file it states that the seed has run for this new tenant (Seeding tenant_name tenant), but there's no data there, only on public schema.
I can see 2 schemas created on `PostgreSQL` db,the `public` and the new one, but it only populates public schema. Why?

Tried putting on `seeds.rb`:

```
Apartment::Tenant.switch!('tenant_name')
```

And:

```
if Apartment::Tenant.current == "tenant_name"...
```

But no good.

Anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, but please make sure these:

1. **Ensure `schema_search_path` in PG:**

Example: `database.yml` should look like:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  schema_search_path: 'public,shared_extensions'
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  prepared_statements: false

development:
  <<: *default
database: your_development_db
```

2. **For `schema`-specific data population, run statement inside tenant `switch` block:**

In `seed.rb`, first create tenant, then switch in that tenant like this:

```
Apartment::Tenant.switch('tenant_name') do
  # Do all stuff here inside this block
  # User.create(user_attributes) will create use only inside `tenant_name` schema
end
```

Cheer!

Comment: Worked for me. Although I am still getting: "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken" like it would be trying to seed tenants with users again.